# Get field-name property on onchage event in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield

I want to check on my custom **onchange** event which fieldName is being changed but when I try to retrieve info via event.detail.fieldName or event.detail.field-name it gives me undefined.

js:

```
handleInputChange(event){
    var eventName = event.detail.fieldname;
    console.log(eventName);
}
```

cmp:

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input-field>
```

How can I get `field-name` value via event in handleInputChange method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`event.detail` will give you the data sent in event and `event.target` (or `event.currentTarget`) will give you the details about the elements.

Currently you are looking for attributes on source element so you should be using `event.target`. Below will give you **fieldName**:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    console.log('fieldName => ', event.target.fieldName);
}
```

[Also note](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_data_binding)

> NOTE Property names in JavaScript are in camel case while HTML
>   attribute names are in kebab case (dash-separated) to match HTML
>   standards. In todoApp.html, the item-name attribute in markup maps to
>   the itemName JavaScript property of c-todo-item.

Same applies even for attributes - called from same component JS.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed!